# Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum? on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

## Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum

I was writing a web scraper and I use Selenium, however this error shows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


import pandas as pd


import time
import datetime


import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/Coding practice/chromedriver.exe")
time.sleep(10)
browser.get("http://www.expedia.com")
time.sleep(10)



def tab_chooser(tab):
    tab = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='tab-flight-tab-hp']")
    time.sleep(10)
    tab.click()
```

The result is, the browser is able to open and go to expedia but not able to click on tab.

Comment: show the complete stacktrace

Comment: At which line do you see the error as per the heading _Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum_?

Comment: `C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Coding practice>python test.py
[21700:9228:0819/204650.390:ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(150)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52022/devtools/browser/f922d104-a4ff-46a5-b197-5388566e3a79`

Comment: I tried subtracting single line of code each time and I found even with just

`browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/Coding practice/chromedriver.exe")`

There will be the error in the heading.